# how to know who have approve/reject a wiki page inside my enterprise wiki

Tags: publishing-site, approval-process, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

I have a publishing site collection using the enterprise wiki template. but i am unable to find a way to know who have approve a wiki page.  ?
Can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an approval process set up for your wiki pages already then you should be able to go to whatever task list you're using with the approval process (Workflow Tasks or Tasks generally).  In that you will see who has approved or rejected what and when they did it.

[image: Here's an image of a completed task with the Publishing Approval Workflow]

Comment: no i am not using an approval process, i just inside my page library setting i enable require content approvals...

Comment: Oh ok.  Does that alone create a task?  Or how do the approvers know that they need to Approve/Reject a page?

Comment: there is a view named "Approve/Reject" which show pending pages..

Comment: but my question is about how me as the site administator can know how approved a page ? as the modifiedBy column will not be affected when a page is approved/rejected...

Comment: I don't think there's an OOTB way to do that without using the Publishing Approval Workflow.  With that it creates a task and you can see all of that info.

Comment: See pic in answer now.  That's what the workflow will give you.

Comment: so if i am not using a workflow there is no way to know how approved the wiki page ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, there needs to be a task in order to see who approved it.  You don't get the task with just the content approval feature alone.